# C++ Linked List - Print in sorted order

Tags: c++, printing, linked-list

I've made a linked list in C++ containing car objects. A car object has a few different attributes, but, for this example we will focus upon the miles per gallon (MPG) attribute. 
This attribute is an int and some cars have identical MPG.

Is there a way for me to print out these items in an increasing order of MPG without actually sorting the linked list, i.e. iterating through the entire list n-times where n = the size of the linked list, outputting a car object to the user with each iteration of the list.

I apologise in advance if my question is not in the correct format, I'm new here.

Comment: make copy of initial list, or list of pointers to objects of initial list, sort it and print. Will result in compact code

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do that.

1. Make an array of false values equal to the size of the list.
2. Take a new object of type car and assign it the first value in the linked list.
3. Iterate over the list trying to find a car with a lower MPG. if found replace it with this one.
4. At the end of each iteration, print this element and mark the corresponding value in the false array as true so that you dont use it again.

Example:

```
CAR    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5-> NULL 

MPG    15   25   10   41   21

arr    F    F    F    F    F
```

After each iteration one by one arr values will become true(ie you've printed them.)

Comment: it won't be faster than sorting.

Comment: @AndreiR. OP didnt want to sort it. He wants to print them in a sorted order using this kind of a technique. Read question details.